# Export Quaternion Data from Imported FBX File to Text File

Tags: python, animation, .fbx

I am importing a motion-captured FBX animation file into Blender and trying to extract the w, x, y, and z quaternion components of each keyframe within the animation for selected nodes into a text file. For example, if I am looking at the leftArm node at frame 0, I would want that entry in the text file to be of the following form: time, w, x, y, z (0.0, 0.998, -0.026, 0.048, -0.034 in my case). This would then be repeated across the entire duration of the animation for that specified node. I am new to coding with Blender and am trying to find the best way to access the quaternion rotations for each node using the python bpy library. I added an image of the hierarchy I see within Blender below. Any assistance towards this would be very appreciated. If you need any more information from me, please let me know. Thanks!

[image: Animation Hierarchy]